# Azure Cosmos DB callin api in postman syntax

Tags: api, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am not able to call the azure db it give me response api key doesn't have permission.
Can you provide me solution and one example.

Comment: Are you trying to call the Cosmos DocumentDB REST API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Postman, you need to add a pre-request script to compose the auth token and prepend it to the request header.

Here is an example from Steve Lindsay (Microsoft TE): 
https://github.com/MicrosoftTE/documentdb-postman-collection

He demonstrates it in a Channel 9 Azure Friday video:
https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Azure-Friday/Using-REST-with-DocumentDB